# What type of Weibull function does "SciPy. Stats. Weibull_min" represent?

Tags: python, scipy

I already know that "scipy.stats.exponweib" refers to the Exponentiated Weibull distribution, so does "scipy.stats.weibull_min" corresponds to the three-parameter Weibull distribution, or the two-parameter Weibull distribution, or the so-called standard Weibull distribution?

It can be seen from the two figures that the formula of "the standard Weibull distribution"

[image: Weibull Distribution formula]

is exactly the same as the formula of "scipy.stats.weibull_min"

[image: scipy.stats.weibull_min dopcumentation]

so what is the standard Weibull distribution?

Finally, I want to fit a three-parameter weibull distribution to my data, should I use "scipy.stats.weibull_min"?

Comment: Your best bet might be to read the source.

Answer (score 0):

> so does `scipy.stats.weibull_min` corresponds to the three-parameter Weibull distribution, or the two-parameter Weibull distribution, or the so-called standard Weibull distribution?

`scipy.stats.weibull_min` can be used in any of these three ways.

For the standard Weibull distribution with `c=2`:

```py
from scipy import stats
# by default, `loc=0` and `scale=1`
standard_weibull = stats.weibull_min(c=2)
```

For the two-parameter Weibull distribution with `c=2` and `scale=1.5`:

```py
twoparam_weibull = stats.weibull_min(c=2, scale=1.5)
```

For the three-parameter Weibull distribution with `c=2`, `scale=1.5`, and `loc=-1`:

```py
treparam_weibull = stats.weibull_min(c=2, scale=1.5, loc=-1)
```

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 300)
pdf1 = standard_weibull.pdf(x)
pdf2 = twoparam_weibull.pdf(x)
pdf3 = treparam_weibull.pdf(x)

plt.plot(x, pdf1, label='standard')
plt.plot(x, pdf2, label='two-parameter')
plt.plot(x, pdf3, label='three-parameter')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

> Finally, I want to fit a three-parameter weibull distribution to my data, should I use "scipy.stats.weibull_min"?

Yes. If you wanted to fit a two-parameter Weibull to your data, you would fix the location with `floc=0`. If you wanted to fit a standard Wibull to your data, you'd also fix the scale with `fscale=1`.

```py
data = standard_weibull.rvs(size=100)
treparam_params = stats.weibull_min.fit(data)
# (1.9201813763802515, 0.009596546763289675, 0.9715998168668463)
twoparam_params = stats.weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0)
# (1.9440072272633722, 0, 0.9547611987999606)
standard_params = stats.weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0, fscale=1)
# (1.9773521741819526, 0, 1)
```